# How do I remove or ignore .rb~ files from git repository?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github, gitignore

I want to remove/igonre/hide whichever is better  `.rb~` and `.#` files such as `.#admin.rb.1.2` from the git repository.

How I can do this?

Currently I am doing it in following way:

```
  git rm -r  "/app/models/.#admin.rb.1.2"
```

which removes the files one by one. Then I commit.

I also created a `.gitignore` file with the following values which I found for Rails:

```
.bundle
db/*.sqlite3*
log/*.log
*.log
/tmp/
doc/
*.swp
*~
.project
.DS_Store
```

But it is not ignoring the files which are already present in the directory.

Will this file ignore `.rb~` backup files?
What should I do so that it will remove all the files which match the expression written in `.gitignore` files?

Comment: This is not a Ruby question and marginally a Rails question, so I removed the Ruby tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files which are already in git will not be ignored anymore. First you have to remove them all and then the .gitignore file is going to ignore the new ones.